# Laravel barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf

I am using Laravel 5.2 and package "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf". I am streaming/viewing the view file like this:

```
$manu = Mmanufacturer::select('manName')->find($manuid);
        $prds = compact('prds','images','temp_header','temp_footer');
        return PDF::loadView('cp.reports.letters-pdf', $prds)->stream();
```

This opens the appropriate view and is working fine... see image:
http://prntscr.com/dflj4d

At the end of url as you see '43' which is id by default..what I want to show at the end is manufacturer/product or something name instead of its id..Can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can set custom routing for view pdf, send parameter by post method. Like:

```
Route::post('/manufacturer/product', 'ReportController@viewPdf');
```

If you use button then use this way:

```
<a href="#!" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('viewPdf').submit();">View Pdf</a>
```

Form For View PDF

```
<form id="viewPdf" action="{{ url('/manufacturer/product') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
       <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="43">
    {{ csrf_field() }}  
</form>
```

In Controller:

```
 $manuid= $request->product_id;
 $manu = Mmanufacturer::select('manName')->find($manuid);
 $prds = compact('prds','images','temp_header','temp_footer');
 return PDF::loadView('cp.reports.letters-pdf', $prds)->stream();
```

Hope this trick will help. Thank You :)